# Test Runner class is not running but able to execute the feature file

Tags: java, eclipse, automation, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have given correct step definition class, but when I tried to execute the Test Runner class , it not executing. But when I run the feature file, the test is getting executed.
Also my code was working before with my existing code and all on a sudden it is not getting executed when I try to run the Test Runner class as Junit test.

[Test Runner Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt3en.png)
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayaYg.png)

```
package org.Cucumber.TestExecution;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"Feature"}
        ,glue={"src.org.Cucumber.StepDefinition"}        
        )

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: Remove the "src." from glue option and run again

Comment: @Grasshopper Thanks, it works